# Macroexpand for parenscript

Tags: macros, common-lisp, parenscript

Is there an equivalent to macroexpand or macroexpand-1 for parenscript macros?  Doing `(ps (some macro expression))` will display the generated javascript, but there are times when it would be nice to see the parenscript just before it gets converted to javascript.

Comment: Hm, you could define the macro as (non parenscript, normal lisp) macro and macro expand it the usual way. I guess that this *should* work for many cases, but it's of course only a hack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In parenscript's `compiler.lisp` file, there are the functions 
`ps-macroexpand-1` and `ps-macroexpand`. Unfortunately, they are not exported by the parenscript package. You can call them anyway using a double colon.

For example,

```
(defpsmacro aif (test true &rest false)
  `(let ((it ,test))
     (if it ,true ,@false)))

(ps::ps-macroexpand-1 '(aif 3 it))
;;=>
(LET ((IT 3))
  (IF IT
      IT))
T
```